# Pagination via page template in Plone

Tags: pagination, plone

I'm looking for a example on how to use the Batch TAL macro for pagination of folder contents. Up to know didn't find any that explains what to do. Does anyone know of such an example?

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Helio

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like that ?

```
<div tal:define="liste python:here.portal_catalog.searchResults({'portal_type' : 'News Item',   'review_state':'published'});
             Batch python:modules['Products.CMFPlone'].Batch;
             b_size python:20;
             b_start python:0;
             b_start request/b_start | b_start;
             batch python:Batch(liste, b_size, int(b_start), orphan=1);"
     tal:condition="liste">

    <ul>

        <tal:boucle tal:repeat="item batch">
            <li tal:define="oddrow repeat/item/odd;" 
                tal:attributes="class python:test(oddrow, 'even', 'odd')">

                 <!-- stuff -->

            </li>
        </tal:boucle>

    </ul>

    <div metal:use-macro="here/batch_macros/macros/navigation" />

</div>
```

Comment: Salut Jihaisse! Mercu beaucoup for the answer :). I had found something just a few minutes before I saw your answer. But yours is better formatted than the one I found. Regards, Helio

Answer (score 2):

Found this resource:

http://raw.zniper.net/bits/batching-in-custom-template

it worked very well.

Regards,
Helio

Comment: This link is not active anymore. The comment should be removed or updated.